# AS3/Flash CS6 - Stop music after Scene?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm a beginner in AS3 and Flash CS6.
I tried to search for a solution, but couldn't find anything that would've worked for me.

I have a small game where you must avoid particles coming at you, and as usual, when you hit one, you goto The End scene.
The problem is that when you replay the game from The End screen, the music won't stop, but start again on top of the other one.
I've included my sound from `Library -> mysound.mp3 -> Properties -> ActionScript3 -> Export for ActionScript & Export in Frame 1`.

Is there a way I could stop the sound from ActionScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way I could stop the sound from ActionScript?

Don't place Sound object on the timeline, control it yourself, It's pretty easy and straightforward.

```
//Start background music somewhere        
var soundFromLibrary: SomeSound = new SomeSound();
var myBackgroundMusic: SoundChannel = soundFromLibrary.play(0, int.MAX_VALUE);

//Now you have reference on background music, stop it
myBackgroundMusic.stop();
```

Comment: Now it plays it twice at the same time. The other one stops at the end, but the other one just keeps going...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the music set on a specific keyframe, then in the properties panel, set it to

```
Sync: Start
Repeat: 1
```

And on the frame where you want to stop the music:

```
Sync: Stop
Repeat: 1
```